# Remove top element of stack without keeping track of index

Tags: java, stack

Is there a way to remove the top element of a stack without keeping track of the index of the top AND without returning the top element? The method pop() returns the removed element, and the method remove() needs the index of the element. 
The thing I really need to do is to remove the top element and I did this by counting the stack index, but I just wanted to know if there was a way to do this without counting stack index.

Comment: Use an `ArrayDeque` which already implements a `Stack`?

Comment: Why not just a blank call to `pop()`? I.e. just ignore the return value and it's as if it never returned anything

Comment: Java points values by reference. So there is no point of `without returning the top element`, as this object will not be cloned. You will get just one more reference to it. Or not(if you will not assign it to any value). Se comment above for same, but shorter answer.

Comment: `public void discard(Stack stack) { stack.pop(); }`

Comment: I didn't know that was possible! Thank you!